# Liferay auto upgrade custom db

Tags: database, liferay

I'm trying to change the build properties update for liferay custom tables made with service builder.
I would like to control if the deploy has to upgrade the database or not, since now it does or does not ramdomly (apparently).
I'm trying to follow this solution: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-642 but I can't set the base.path property... Where should I put it in order to use it successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found where to put my custom properties and that is in:
include-and-override=${base.path}/service-ext.properties as said before.

But... If the last deployed packet had the build.auto.upgrade=false, you change the database schema, build the services and deploy forgetting to set build.auto.upgrade=true there will be obviously no change. Then if you set build.auto.upgrade=true without building another time the services there will be another time no change, and this is why I was confused before.

Another thing to remember is that if you delete the service-ext.properties file in your project and deploy it, the old file service-ext.properties in the server will not be deleted and will continue to be used, so you have to delete it manually.

Answer (score 0):

In your portlet at below path

your-custom-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/service.properties

Which will have below properties

```
##
## Properties Override
##

    #
    # Specify where to get the overridden properties. Updates should not be made
    # on this file but on the overridden version of this file.
    #
    include-and-override=${base.path}/service-ext.properties

##
## Build below properties will be specific to your portlet as this file is auto generated one it is created / updated while you do ant build-service
##

    build.namespace=SN
    build.number=5
    build.date=1379913470395
    build.auto.upgrade=true
```

Comment: I don't understand, these are the properties I'm trying to override and I should put them on    

${base.path}/service-ext.properties     

But I do not know how to set base.path property... Or it is set somewhere else? In any case, where do I have to put service-ext.properties file?

Comment: It will by default look for service-ext.properties file in same directory where your service.properties is, So you create service-ext.properties with your updated properties and place in same directory. If it does not pick the file correctly update below properties in service.properties with absolute path i.e. include-and-override=c:liferay6.1/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets/social-networking-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/service-ext.properties. Reference Link http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/configuring-serviceproperties-liferay-portal-6-1-dev-guide-en